# in matlab, what differences are between linsolve and mldivide?

Tags: matlab, linear-solver

in matlab, both [linsolve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html) and [mldivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) are used for solving a system of linear equations, in all of determined, overdetermined and underdetermined cases.

Reading their documents, I was wondering what differences are between them? Are they using almost the same algorithms of matrix factorization and triangularization in the three cases?

> If A has the properties in opts, linsolve is faster than mldivide, because linsolve does not perform any tests to verify that A has the specified properties

Does mldivide perform the same tests to verify if A has the special properties? Or does mldivide just treat them as general case without the special properties?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both of them are direct solver to solve linear systems (opposing to iterative solver).

`mldivide` does perform the tests for $A$ in solving $Ax = b$. Please see [Allan's answer in this thread](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/how-does-the-matlab-backslash-operator-solve-ax-b-for-square-matrices) for more information.  Also see MATLAB's help on [`mldivide` algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/systems-of-linear-equations.html) here.

> `mldivide` for square matrices: If A is symmetric and has real, positive diagonal elements, MATLAB attempts a Cholesky factorization. If the Cholesky factorization fails, MATLAB performs a symmetric, indefinite factorization. If A is upper Hessenberg, MATLAB uses Gaussian elimination to reduce the system to a triangular matrix. If A is square but is neither permuted triangular, symmetric and positive definite, or Hessenberg, then MATLAB performs a general triangular factorization using LU factorization with partial pivoting
>
> `linsolve` for square matrices: LU factorization with partial pivoting
>
> `mldivide` and `linsolve` for rectangular matrices: QR factorization

In `linsolve` as the help doc suggests in mathworks website, you could avoid the extra testing process (Allan used the word "overhead" in his answer) by using `opts` if and only if you *know* what $A$ is like in advance. For large problems, you could save some time. For example:

```
opts.POSDEF = true; linsolve(A,b,opts)
```

would return $x$ if you know $A$ is positive definite in advance. However, an incorrectly chosen `opts` leads to a wrong result.

If certain criteria are met, `linsolve` and `mldivide` do utilize the same factorization process. For example, for a *dense* positive definite system satisfying certain properties, or you have an overdetermined system and both perform least square fitting.

Moreover, `linsolve` could also perform [symbolic computation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/linsolve.html). This is handy when you have a small underdetermined system which has infinite number of solutions. `linsolve` enables you to solve it symbolically, `mldivide` can not do that. However, if the variables are not declared symbolically, `mldivide` and `linsolve` would give you the same warning message "Matrix is singular to working precision."

Last but not least, `linsolve` does not support *sparse* systems like the following matrix (blue dot means non-zero entry). While `mldivide` could handle sparse systems robustly when the size is under 200k by 200k.
[image: sparse example]