# How to solve a Stiffness matrix?

Tags: finite-element, matlab

I am quite new in this field. For my university I prepared a stiffness matrix to solve for a project group. This matrix consists of 450 equations with 450 unknows (it's a Matlab script) and I have the associated load vector $\{L\}$ of 450 rows. since I need to calculate the displacements would you advice me to simply do $\{x\} = [K]^{-1}  \{L\}$?

Comment: Just use any routine for solving linear systems, as inverting a matrix must be avoided. In MatLab, you have the backslash. Look the documentation on mathworkds, you'll find anything you need

Comment: This is such a small problem that matlab's backslash operator is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by Wolfgang Bangerth, for this problem you want to use the [backslash](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96919-how-does-the-backslash-operator-work-when-a-is-full) [operator](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1001/9667), i.e.,

```matlab
u = K \ L;
```

In general, you don't want to reinvent the wheel and should go with a linear algebra library for this kind of problem.

**PS:** Keep in mind that your stiffness matrix might be singular if you haven't imposed any constraints.